# startswith() can't find '//' at the front of my string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a pretty simple python script that reads in a file, and parses it line by line.

It doesn't seem to recognize the '//' at the start of my lines.  If I change it to look for '#' at the start of my lines, it doesn't find those lines either.  Am I just misunderstanding this?

```
line = fIn.readline()

while line:
    print "line is", line
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('//'):
        print "winner"
    line = fIn.readline()
```

The file I'm reading in looks like this:

```
// Feedback
"Feedback" = "Feedback";

// New strings
"File URL not reachable." = "File URL not reachable.";
```

And the debug line looks appropriate when it prints out:

```
line is // Feedback

line is "Feedback" = "Feedback";

line is 

line is // New strings

line is "File URL not reachable." = "File URL not reachable.";

line is
```

Comment: You should really be using `for line in fIn` here, rather than `fIn.readline()`

Comment: could you try something like '//' in line and see if that is true? I'm having trouble reproducing this :/

Comment: This works fine for me if I deindent the `line = fIn.readline()` (otherwise the loop never finishes). Are you sure the code you posted is what you're running?

Comment: works fine here, and no, he can't be getting that output with the last line indented as it is... please run your own example before posting

Comment: Look at the edit history... someone changed my indentation when they edited my post (like indentation doesn't matter in Python)

Comment: More information is definitely required, because the code (once everyone is on the same page regarding indentation) works for the data you've given.  Did you simplify the code *or the data* and simply construct the output to resemble what you're seeing (rather than actually pasting the output to Stack Overflow)?

Comment: It is looking to me like there is some weirdness in the file I'm working from.  Even though it prints out fine in my test statements, there is something odd about it.  I have been able to find a work around thanks to @JaynathanLeung as I can get it to recognize like '/' in the line.

Comment: One thing to try (if you still care about getting to the bottom of the mystery) is printing `repr(line)` instead of just `line`.  Also, if you're handy with a hex editor, use that to look at your input file.  That should clear up any issues with the file in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better version:

```
with open("abc") as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip()
        if line and line.startswith("//"):
            print "line is",line
            print "winner"
            print next(f)
   ....:
```

**output:**

```
line is // Feedback
winner
"Feedback" = "Feedback";

line is // New strings
winner
"File URL not reachable." = "File URL not reachable.";
```

Comment: I'm reading extra lines from the file, depending on contents, after the "winner".  Could I still read extra lines within that looop?

Comment: @HalR yes you can, just use `print next(f)` after `print "winner"`.

Comment: Why use `next()` which doesn't work if there are two lines aftee the winner, rather than just printing every line regardless of the if sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading one line of your text file. Other than you have the wrong indent on the last line, it seems to work. Try running your program after making sure `line = fIn.readline()` gets executed on each iteration (move it one block to the left).

Here is what I get after fixing that one line, is this the desired output?

```
line is // Feedback

winner
line is "Feedback" = "Feedback";

line is  

line is // New strings

winner
line is "File URL not reachable." = "File URL not reachable.";
```

Edit: does this work for you?

```
for line in open("yourfile.txt").readlines():
    print "line is", line
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('//'):
        print "winner"
```

Comment: If he's only reading one line, why is the debug output showing all the lines? I think his indentation got screwed up when he pasted into SO (a big problem for indentation-sensitive languages like Python)

Comment: Using `file.readlines()` just to iterate over is a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for line in fIn:
    print "line is", line
    line = line.strip()
    if line[0:2]=='//':
        print "winner"
        line = fIn.readline()
```